# What is the structure from which a sign is hung called?

Tags: single-word-requests

My grandparents had a structure at the last cattle guard before their ranch house from which a sign with the name of their ranch hung.

It was two vertical poles, with a horizontal crossbeam, I guess it would be called, from which the sign hung.

What is that contraption/structure called? "They had a sign with the name of their ranch, the Walking S, hanging from ..."

Comment: All I've found is 'ranch entrance signs'. The signs themselves are 'hanging signs' (but this is a blanket term, covering signs hanging from brackets, as pub signs usually do).

Comment: Misreading "cattle" as "castle" made the question seem much more impressive

Comment: Generically, it could be called a frame, but a border around the sign could also be called a frame, so I don't think that's a good answer or what you're looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The wooden ones in these [pictures](https://www.google.com/search?q=ranch%20archway&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwib3PX_-L30AhUtQkIHHS1XBEcQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=ranch%20archway&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEOgcIIxDvAxAnOgYIABAFEB5Q7QRYkghg8QloAHAAeACAAY8BiAGgA5IBAzMuMZgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=fvmkYZulKq2EieoPra6RuAQ&bih=758&biw=1488&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS911US911) are described as (ranch) *arches, archways, entrances* and *gates*, even when there is no moveable gate to close off the entrance. Most of them in the illustrations display the place name.

Answer (score 16):

I'd go for...

> **gantry**  [(Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gantry)
> *A gantry is a high metal structure that supports a set of road signs, railway signals, or other equipment.*

---

[image]

The fact that that *particular* definition says *a **metal** structure* isn't significant to me. Functionally it's the same thing if it's made of wood.

Comment: If you take off  "gantry" from  your search string ("ranch entry" or "ranch entrance"), you get similar pictures, but not for "gantry" alone. Also, if you search in images, I don't think any of the captions have "gantry."

Comment: I'm not claiming "gantry" has this particular meaning very specifically. But I don't believe there's any similarly well-known term that's any *more* accurate for the specific sense, which is why I said ***I'd go for** [the best available word, imho]*. The most famous such structure must surely be the one at [the main gate of Auschwitz concentration camp](https://www.escape2poland.co.uk/poland-guide/arbeit-macht-frei), but I skimmed the text of several pages about that without finding anything better than "gantry".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks, the second picture looks very much like their sign, too.

Answer (score 1):

## Gateway sign: Specifically a Ranch Gateway Sign

A gateway sign is any sign that demarcates a boundary between properties, regions or towns. It is always associated with an entranceway, usually a road entrance.
It *can* be along the side of the road, but is more usually seen over the accessway.

Over
[image]
or to the side
[image]

The "Ranch" variety is almost always an overhead structure.
[image]

The actual "gate" of the gateway is often omitted.

Comment: Great; I'll probably go with "Ranch Gateway sign" after all.

Answer (score 0):

Confusingly, these are called sign standards. This, of course, makes it horrible to search for since all you get is regs and guidance for signage. However, building sign standards and occasionally installing them and their signage is one of the jobs I did under contract with the USFS in Colorado.

http://npshistory.com/publications/orca/clr.pdf (see page 41 of the PDF)

[image]

Now I'm not sure how useful this answer is, because it doesn't appear to be a well known term outside of landscape architecture and signage people.